# Extract report from multiple queries with Toad from Oracle

Tags: oracle, toad

Is it possible to extract an Excel with multiple dataset populated from multiple queries? I need to get a report.

Currently I launch every query and I extract the resultset in a separate excel.

Comment: in Excel 2007+ you can create multiple data connections to oracle directly from Excel.. would that be an option?

Comment: Can you explain how to do it better? Can I write queries in standard ANSI SQL? How do I specify a parameter?

Comment: oh,, parameters? that would require some VBA, not in the scope of a `toad` question..

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  If you use the "Excel Instance" export option, TOAD checks to see if an instance of Excel is already open.  If so, it writes to a new sheet in that instance.  If you've selected the "Start at active cell" option, it starts at the active cell rather than a new sheet.

Comment: Thanks, are there any other methods?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/10893_3358411_3/Connecting-with-Oracle-Accessing-Oracle-via-Access-and-Excel.htm. You cac connect to oracle from Excel and view the data from excel.

Comment: Can you explain how to do it better? Can I write queries in standard ANSI SQL? How do I specify a parameter?